# car stalls when any torque applied

Tags: stall

My dad has a Ford Falcon AU auto that has stopped working...

1. The car is idling quite rough and has a tendency to stall.
2. If left to idle it'll stall after a minute or so
3. You can rev it hard when it is in park and it'll be mostly ok
4. if you put it into drive it'll then move a forward slowly (normal for an auto)
5. as soon as the accelerator is applied while in drive it stalls

We've changed the spark plugs and replaced the fuel pump.

Comment: Could be too much fuel injected in the cylinders. It just drowning its spark plugs in gasoline.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issues in my Volvo V70 and it was due to a faulty ignition cable. Check if you can see any sparks jumping over from the cable to any metal parts of the car.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a misfire to me. Id say check plug wires and distributor cap and make sure they are working properly too(timing as well). New spark plugs wont do you any good if the spark doesnt even make it to them or if its going to the wrong cylinder.